# Apply a function in a dataframe's columns [Python]

Tags: python, function, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I just wrote this function to calculated the age's person based in two columns in a Python DataFrame. Unfortunately, if a use the `return` the function return the same value for all rows, but if I use the `print` statement the function gives me the right values.

Here is the code:

```
def calc_age(dataset):
    index = dataset.index
    for element in index:
        year_nasc = train['DT_NASCIMENTO_BENEFICIARIO'][element][6:]
        year_insc = train['ANO_CONCESSAO_BOLSA'][element]
        age = int(year_insc) - int(year_nasc)
        print ('Age: ', age)
        #return age
```

`train['DT_NASCIMENTO_BENEFICIARIO'] = 03-02-1987`

`train['ANO_CONCESSAO_BOLSA'] = 2009`

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Please post a subset of your dataset and the output you are looking for

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QbadA-CHSjNrPvDN0UuIx1NQwyTWnJyU/view?usp=sharing this is a little sample

Comment: That's how a `return` statement works. Once your function hits a return statement, it returns to the caller function immediately. If you un-comment the return statement, it will return the value of `age` for the first index, no matter how many rows you have. It won't even process the next indices.

What do you expect from this function?

Comment: I was trying to get the age for every line in the DataFrame, based in that formula.

Comment: In that case, you can store these ages into a list and return the list _after_ the loop.

Comment: You mean I have to append the results in a list and then return it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to subtract the year of `DT_NASCIMENTO_BENEFICIARIO` from `ANO_CONCESSAO_BOLSA`, and `df` is your DataFrame:

```
# cast to datetime
df["DT_NASCIMENTO_BENEFICIARIO"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DT_NASCIMENTO_BENEFICIARIO"])
df["age"] = df["ANO_CONCESSAO_BOLSA"] - df["DT_NASCIMENTO_BENEFICIARIO"].dt.year

# print the result, or do something else with it:
print(df["age"])
```